# How to put (or simulate putting) two "align" environments next to each other?

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I am having trouble with the `align` environment. I wrote the following code almost works, but not quite:

```
\begin{align*}
\min_{x, y} \ &2x + 4y          &      & \min     \    &9x^2 + 2y  \\
\text{s.t.} \ &2x^2 - 4y \le 7  & \iff & \text{s.t.} \ &2x^2 - 4y \le 7 \\
              &3x+2y \ge 4      &      &               &3x+2y \ge 4  
\end{align*}
```

Output:

[image]

I like how the problem looks on the left side. But on the right, the spacing is wrong. How can I make the problem on the right look like the one on the left?

Thank you very much!

Comment: you are missing a `&`  in every row before the second block so  `&&\min`, `&&\text` , `&&`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot. What is actually going on when you put `&` vs `&&`? From my understanding, when you make an `align` environment, the `&` are used to separate "columns". So it seems to me that `&&` just makes an empty column.

Comment: align columns are like an array with `{rl@{\quad}rl@{\quad}rl...)` you want to arrange each `a&=b` equation is in a `rl` pair so they align towards the =, You had got out of sync so `a&=b`  aligned as `l@{\quad}r`  so the equation is pulled apart.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So if you put `A & B & C & D`, LaTeX assumes that there is an equal sign between `A, B` and between `C, D`, i.e. you are trying to display `A = B  C = D`?

Comment: yes, alignat as used by @mico is similar but with `rlrlrl` ie no extra space which is why the added an extra `\quad` in the body

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah okay. I didn't know that `aling` assumes that some `&`'s are for equal signs, and some are to separate columns. I thought they all `&`'s separate columns. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'alignat*' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
\min_{x, y}\ &2x + 4y         &&                &        \min\ &9x^2 + 2y  \\
\text{s.t.}\ &2x^2 - 4y \le 7 &&\qquad\iff\qquad& \text{s.t.}\ &2x^2 - 4y \le 7 \\
             &3x+2y \ge 4     &&                &              &3x+2y \ge 4  
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What is actually going on when you put `&` vs `&&`? From my understanding, when you make an align environment, the `&` are used to separate "columns". So it seems to me that `&&` just makes an empty column.

Comment: see my comment under the question re `&&` @user56202